# Apache2 not loading PHP 8.0.5 - returns php as text not executing

Tags: 20.04, apache2, php

#### Issue

I updated my `PHP` version from `7.2` to `8.0.5`

I followed [this guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-php-8-on-ubuntu-20-04/) to update my PHP

I ran this `sudo apt-get purge php7.*` to remove my php 7 version.

Now when I browse to my website i just get the php codeliek

```php
<?php

/* ton of code here */
```

when I enable

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
sudo a2enconf php8.0-fpm
```

i get an error of

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later
```

when browsing to the website

#### Edit 1:

```
[Sat May 22 12:21:03.453315 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 511723] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock (*) fai>
[Sat May 22 12:21:03.453398 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 511723] [client 102.223.225.133:63119] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

#### Edit 2:

after running `sudo systemctl list-units --failed`
i see

```
● php8.0-fpm.service     loaded failed failed The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager
```

#### Edit 3:

my apache user is `safe-www`

#### Edit 4:

/var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Sat May 22 12:33:52.354558 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2763] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat May 22 12:33:52.354654 2021] [core:notice] [pid 2763] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

site.error.log

```
[Sat May 22 12:33:54.737169 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 2765] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock (*) failed
[Sat May 22 12:33:54.737233 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2765] [client 102.223.225.133:63281] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

#### Edit 5:

/var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Sat May 22 12:45:10.817186 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5482] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat May 22 12:45:10.817273 2021] [core:notice] [pid 5482] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2
```

site.error.log

```
AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Sat May 22 12:45:13.311597 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5484] (22)Invalid argument: [client 102.223.225.133:63477] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

#### Edit 6:

```
[ - ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  atd
 [ + ]  chrony
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  cryptdisks
 [ - ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  iscsid
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ + ]  multipath-tools
 [ - ]  open-iscsi
 [ - ]  open-vm-tools
 [ + ]  php8.0-fpm
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  screen-cleanup
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

#### Edit 7:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64432303/6651840)

Comment: What do you see in your Apache logs? There should be something in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file or one of the site-specific error logs letting you know why you are getting a 503 error code.

Comment: @matigo see edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you uninstalled PHP 7.x *after* installing PHP 8.0, then there was probably a bit of overlap that has taken out your PHP 8.0 installation. A slight re-install might be in order.

Try this:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall php8.0 libapache2-mod-php8.0
sudo a2enconf php8.0-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That will re-load PHP 8.0, ensure the modules are in place and intact, enable the FastCGI Process Manager, then restart Apache. *Generally*, this is the process that people need to follow when a similar issue happens with PHP7.x.

***Following up ...***

The `AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS` is sometimes caused by a bum service that needs to be restarted. I don't use PHP8.0, so can't guess at the name of the service, but you can list all services running on your system like this:

```
sudo service --status-all
```

This will give you a list of services with a `[-]` to signify it's inactive, and `[+]` to mean it's running. You will want to look for a service that looks something like `php80-php-fpm` and restart it:

```
sudo service php80-php-fpm restart
```

This may resolve the issue.

***If Contending with a Proxy Issue ...***

On occasion there may be an issue if using `proxy_fcgi` and the send buffers do not fill one frame of data. This can be worked around by editing the Apache configuration for the affected site to include this:

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
    ProxyPassMatch ^(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

Hopefully this resolves the final issue.

Comment: still not working

Comment: please see edit 4

Comment: "Not working" is an incomplete statement, as your FastCGI Process Manager is actually loading now. The "file not found" issue is new :P

Comment: Glad we getting there, not sure what to do man, I've never had this issue before. plz help :)

Comment: added an edit..

Comment: see edit for results of `sudo service --status-all` command

Comment: only issue i got is this `AH01070: Error parsing script headers`

Comment: if i running this `sudo a2dismod proxy_fcgi setenvif` then the webpage loads, but the then the controller doesnt load when i click the login button it posts to `/login` i get a 404 error

Comment: Another update for you to examine.

Comment: i have multiple projects `/var/www/website` and `/var/www/test` so where do i put that proxypass code?

Comment: In every enabled Apache config you have in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Comment: "Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module"

Comment: You'll need to enable headers: `sudo a2enmod headers` ... and probably rewrite `sudo a2enmod rewrite` ... then restart Apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: now i get `No protocol handler was valid for the URL /index.php (scheme 'fcgi'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule`

Comment: ok i got it working now, thanks bro..... see last edit

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy). The upgrade installed php8.1 and after that apache did not execute .php files anymore. There were no error messages in error.log.

I was sure that I had all the necessary packages for php8.1 installed. What finally fixed it for me was this:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```